# Is there a way to remove a query string from a drupal 8 form action?

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-8

I'm making a multistep form. I want the same url for each step. My FormTwo has an external action so the user data goes straight to the card processing folk, Eway. So my stage two form isn't handled by my drupal site instead it is handled by Eway. On submission of the stage two form the user is sent back to www.my-site.com/payment?AccessCode=blahblahblah by Eway.

I can get the access code with *\Drupal::request()->query->get('AccessCode')* but *\Drupal::request()->query->remove('AccessCode')* only removes the query string from that record so the action of the generated form ends up being www.my-site.com/payment?AccessCode=blahblahblah . I'd like it to be www.my-site.com/payment.

```
  public function stageThree(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $access_code = \Drupal::request()->query->get('AccessCode');
    if (strlen($access_code)) {
      \Drupal::request()->query->remove('AccessCode');

      // do stuff with access code
      $failed = true;

    }

    // Something like this for failed result. No form for success.

    if ($failed) {
        $form['message'] = [
          '#markup' => "<p>Try again</p>",
        ];
        $form['submit'] = [
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#value' => $this->t('Back'),
          '#submit' => ['::stageThreeSubmit'],
          '#validate' => ['::stageThreeValidate'],
        ];
    }
    return $form;
  }

  public function stageThreeSubmit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form_state->set('stage', 2);
    $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
  }
```

I read that using *\Drupal::request()* should be avoided so I'm hoping there is another option that actually works.
Thanks.

Comment: The `AccessCode` query parameter in the URL was from the last step. If it was part of the POST variables then it should be fine. Where did that `AccessCode` get there in the first place?

Comment: The `AccessCode` parameter is added by Eway. I've provided more details in the main question. @koala-yeung

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my approach. Instead of using $form_state to pass values around like in https://git.drupalcode.org/project/examples/blob/8.x-1.x/form_api_example/src/Form/MultistepForm.php I'm using the privateTempStoreFactory class like in https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-multi-step-forms-in-drupal-8/ which means I no longer need to remove the query string.

This doesn't answer the question rather makes the question no longer necessary, to me at least.